# How to use React-Transition-Group to show and hide modal/dialog with animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-transition-group

I've built a modal/dialog component using `React` and `Tailwind`. Here is a [codesandbox with my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-eqbhh?file=/src/App.js).

Now I would like to show and hide the modal with a nice animation like [this one here](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/modals).

I've tried creating this using the [react-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) package.

**My problem**

Currently I have only managed to get it to work on `entering` the dom **BUT** that is while wrapping the entire `Confirm.jsx` component. This is not ideal because that would mean that everytime I want to use the `Confirm.jsx` somewhere in my app, I also have to wrap it with the `<CSSTransition>` component.

So Ideally, I want to add the `<CSSTransition>` component either in `Confirm.jsx` or `Dialog.jsx` but whatever I try, I cannot get these to work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the little [change](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-0s0iz) I've made.

I moved CSSTransition to your `Confirm` component and removed the early returns in `Confirm` and `Dialog` when `open` state is `false`

You were returning nothing when `open` state is set to null. This was canceling your exit animation. CSSTransition needs to have someting to render so that it can add exit animation classes while exiting. After the animation is complete, CSSTransition removes the childtren from the DOM as you have already set the unmountOnExit property